# OpenLDAP not letting me add users

Tags: openldap, redhat

I am trying to set up a standalone OpenLDAP on a RHEL box, but I am having a bit of trouble when trying to import users into the system.

If I enter the following command:

```
ldapadd -x -h localhost -D 'cn=Users,dc=internal,dc=priv' -W -f user.ldif
```

I get the following response:

```
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

While on the ldap server itself, the following appears:

```
slap_listener_activate(7):
>>> slap_listener(ldap:///)
connection_get(11): got connid=1
connection_read(11): checking for input on id=1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 45 contents:
ber_get_next
do_bind
ber_scanf fmt ({imt) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (m}) ber:
>>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Users,dc=internal,dc=priv>
<<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Users,dc=internal,dc=priv>, <cn=users,dc=internal,dc=priv>
do_bind: version=3 dn="cn=Users,dc=internal,dc=priv" method=128
send_ldap_result: conn=1 op=0 p=3
send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=49
ber_flush: 14 bytes to sd 11
connection_get(11): got connid=1
connection_read(11): checking for input on id=1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next on fd 11 failed errno=0 (Success)
connection_closing: readying conn=1 sd=11 for close
connection_close: conn=1 sd=11
```

I don't know LDAP that well - can anyone suggest a way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to your LDAP DB as the user who has credentials for modifying the database. One way is to use the manager user (`rootdn somethinghere`) defined in *slapd.conf* file.

So, if you have `rootdn cn=TheMightyRootUser,ou=users,dc=internal,dc=priv` in slapd.conf, provide that `cn=TheMightyRootUser,ou=users,dc=internal,dc=priv` as -D parameter for ldapadd.

Answer (score 0):

-D 'cn=Users,dc=internal,dc=priv' probably doesn't make sense. I guess that you want to add a user to ou=Users,dc=internal,dc=priv. ou denotes a subtree in LDAP. cn denotes a LDAP record.

-D should be followed by the entry that contains the LDAP admin account ('binddn').

cn=Users,etc. would be a weird name for the admin user.

May guess there's no cn=Users,etc. You should probably replace it with cn=admin,dc=internal,dc=priv (quotes are superfluous). You should edit the ldif file to reflect the fact that you want to place the entries in the ou=Users subtree

Another possibility is that your LDAP installation is using SASL, not simple authentication (denoted by -x)